# Getting GooglePlaces API (and asynchronous calls in general) data for AppleWatch (using WCSession)

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, apple-watch, nsoperationqueue

So - after a lot of playing - I figured out a way to make it work, yet I have one thing that I didn't figure out how to bypass (and drives me crazy..).

I have an app for the watch that needs data from GooglePlaces (no interface for iOS yet...). So - I use WCSession, and use the phone, using `sendMessage`, to query GooglePlaces through the phone, returning the nearby places to the watch.

To begin, it appears GooglePlaces `currentPlace` function is called on the same thread it is being called to (by queueing it for later) -- a problem since it is scheduled to when after the program is closed (since the function `didReceiveMessage` exits before it is called). So instead of running it on the main queue, I start a thread and run this code on it....

An issue with it is that `replyHandler` must be called before `session:didReceiveMessage` is finishing execution (otherwise the process is killed if the app is in background mode).

So the code I built to bypass this issue looks like that (Note I have a nested cloudKit code in there.. ):

```
let queue = OperationQueue();

var finishedRunning = false;
queue.addOperation{
    sleep(1);
    self.placesClient?.currentPlace(callback: {
        (placeLikelihoodList: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList?, error: Error?) -> () in
        if let err = error {
            retVal.removeAll();
            retVal["error"] = err.localizedDescription;
            finishedRunning = true;
            return;
        }

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "selected = 1");
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "someInfo", predicate: predicate);

        let privDb = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase;
        privDb.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {records, error in

            if let err = error {
                retVal.removeAll();
                retVal["error"] = err.localizedDescription;
                finishedRunning = true;
                return;
            }
            retVal["completed"] = 1;
            finishedRunning = true;
         });
    });
 }

 while !finishedRunning{
     sleep(1);
 }
 marker = true;
 replyHandler(retVal);
```

Those who read the code carefully noticed I added a `sleep(1);` command up there... immediately after beginning the queue.

It is unclear for me why, but without this sleep call, the GooglePlaces callback is not called!!

I would really like to remove this specific call..
Does anybody have an idea why it happens?
How to bypass it?

(P.S. I am not sure if locks are necessary to protect `finishedRunning`.. since it works, I assume none are necessary).

P.S. #2 - I know it is "dirty", but there is no other way to bypass that ... since I want this data on the watch, I gave up on elegancy...

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not true in my experience: _"An issue with it is that replyHandler must be called before session:didReceiveMessage is finishing execution (otherwise the process is killed if the app is in background mode)."_; what are you basing that upon?

Comment: Debugging , and other posts here...

Comment: I'd might be wrong here, but it behaves weirdly when any asynchronous method is called..

Comment: What do you mean by weirdly?

Comment: It begins running, and the application exits before places executes its callback. (When the app is not running and the watch calls send message) .  If I understand you correctly - it should work with sending the reply handler to the callback function, but it didn't work for me .. the app just exited before the callback function was called

Comment: This all sounds very strange. Perhaps it is some sort of consequence of something in the GooglePlaces code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be different than what I expected...

It appears the `NSUserDefaults` is not "waiting" for itself to be loaded before giving access to its content:
In my code, I read a config before it. 
The code for that was:

```
let config :UserDefaults = UserDefaults();
// read config
```

Had to change to:

```
let config :UserDefaults = UserDefaults();
config.synchronize();
// read config
```

This is because without the synchronize, the watch code ran faster than the asynchronous loading of the config... which lead to a `nil` returned from a config that I expected having...

This resulted in the code dying, and killing the whole session..

The one second delay allowed the asynchronous process to complete loading, and return the expected value...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the `sendMessage`'s `replayHandler` does not have to be called before the delegate method returns, but if you do wish to maintain that behavior you could get rid of at least one of the `sleep(1) so with:

```
<...>
queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
marker = true;
replyHandler(retVal);
```

I don't know anything about the GooglePlaces API so I don't know why that other sleep would be necessary. All that said, because I don't believe the basic assumption that the `replayHandler` must be called before the delegate method returns it would probably be better switching to a more async way of doing this task.

Comment: That was my initial code, but the application process started and exited immediately, assuming the function was called, and after it returned the process was closed.. either way, I'll try the wait function later today and keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: So I am now sure (after contacting apple support) that the the main thread must be held alive with the replyHandler is called - but I am not sure yet if the replyHandler has to be called from the main thread.. (appears like it might)...

I will keep on updating here.. still struggling with this issue...